# Вопрос по сетке адаптива @media на сколько уменьшать контейнер?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

недавно начал изучать адаптивную верстку. Допустим ширина ограниченного контейнера 1200px ну с учетом падинга 1230

```
__container{

max-width:1230px;

margin: 0 auto;

padding:0 15px

}
```

есть три media запроса
1-по ширине ограничивающего контейнера
2-для планшета 992px
3-для мобилки 768px

Собственно сам вопрос. На сколько нужно уменьшать сам ограничивающий контейнер? если изначально он 1230px то каким он должен быть когда будет второй медиа запрос на планшете 992px? т.е когда буду верстать под планшет и под мобилку на сколько px уменьшать нужно ограничивающий контейнер?

```
@media(max-width: 992px){
__container{
max-width ???}
}
```

ну и на мобильном устройстве

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
__container{
max-width ???}
```

на сколько ограничивающий контейнер должен быть меньше? Что-то смотрел на ютубе многих блогеров и этот момент никак не оговаривается

Comment: Это же все индивидуально под каждый проект и макет.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от макета, по которому верстаете.

Ширина контейнера может быть как 100%, так и ограниченная, к примеру, на `@media(max-width: 992px)` ширину контейнера можно ограничить до 768px, а для `@media(max-width: 767px)` контейнер можно ограничить до 450px.

Вообще вам никто не запрещает и на `@media(max-width: 1200px)` ограничить контейнер до 320px, но за такое можно получить по шапке.